# Why is var.First() causing performance issues?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0

Im using .NET 4.0 c#.
I just realised today that a performance issue was partially caused by this :

```
var feuilleDeTemps =
    from fdt in context.FeuilleDeTemps.Include("FeuilleDeTempsJournees");
...
feuilleDeTemps.First().Property
feuilleDeTemps.First().Property
feuilleDeTemps.First().Property
feuilleDeTemps.First().Property
...
FeuilleDeTemps myFT = feuilleDeTemps.First();
return myFT;
```

I was using the first element of feuilleDeTemps (about 4 times per loop x 60 loops) before setting it in a normal variable like this :

```
FeuilleDeTemps myFT = feuilleDeTemps.First();
```

Then i realised it was causing a performance issue. I used this instead :

```
var feuilleDeTemps =
    from fdt in context.FeuilleDeTemps.Include("FeuilleDeTempsJournees");
FeuilleDeTemps myFT = feuilleDeTemps.First();
...
myFT.Property
myFT.Property
myFT.Property
myFT.Property
...
return myFT;
```

I was using feuilleDeTemps.First().Property about 240 times.
Now im using it 60 times and the 240 uses of the property goes directly by the Typed Variable.
It made my code take 2x less time to execute (3 seconds vs 6 seconds which is still pretty slow)...

Why?

Comment: 1 trip to the database or many. Hmmmm....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query you stored in `feuilleDeTemps` isn't actually executed until you request a value. In your case this happens when you call `First`. Generating the query object is usually very fast. It is the execution of the query that usually takes the most time. In your example you are executing the same query multiple times, resulting in several round-trips to the database.

It's important when using LINQ to remember that there is a difference between a *query*, and the *results* of that query. In general queries are executed lazily - no data is fetched until you actually ask for it, e.g. with `First`, `ToList`, `foreach (var result in query)`, etc...

Comment: So by doing var.First() each time i am re-executing the querry every time?

Comment: @Gab There is a good possibility :-) Unless you "materialize" the result set with a ToList(). That will force the query to be executed and the result to be saved.

Comment: This. Linq's designed to work "lazily"; nothing happens with regards to the actual data until you need actual data. the First() method call requires a real value, and so the method chain or expression tree that was built behind the scenes is evaluated at that time, incurring all the expense of computation and network transmission.

Comment: Yep. You sure are. Take a look at using SqlProfiler from the sql server developer edition. It will show you each time the db is hit as well as the query that's created by Linq2SQL or Linq2Entities. (assuming you're going against sql server)

Comment: @Gab: Yes, you are re-executing the query every time. **The result might have changed between the previous execution and the current execution.** The compiler doesn't know whether a nanosecond or ten days have passed between the two calls, and even if it was a nanosecond, the database might have changed in that time.

Comment: @Gab [Here's a great blog post on this subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2007/12/09/deferred-execution.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You are touching the database **four times** on the first code.

The second one, touches the database **once** and the data is available after that line.

That's how Entity Framwork roll, man :D

Comment: ­>.< so much time wasted on finding that. Thnx alot